# Why was Kestra Troi played by two actresses?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, actors

In the Next Generation episode "Dark Page" the viewer learns that Deanna Troi had an older sister named Kestra. During the memory sequence when Lwaxana remembers how Kestra died Kestra is played by Kirsten Dunst. However, just a few moments later when Lwaxana comes to term with Kestra's death, Kestra is portrayed by Andreana Weiner.

It makes sense that the first time Kestra appears in Lwaxana's mind, in the Enterprise setting, that she would appear as Kirsten/Hedril, since the character Hedril was what had triggered Lwaxana's recollection of Kestra to begin with. But during the actual memory of Kestra's death this switch doesn't make a lot of sense.

Why was Kestra played by Kirsten in the picnic setting portraying her death?

Kirsten Dunst as Kestra at the picnic before her death
[image: Kirsten Dunst as Kestra]

Andreana Weiner as Kestra
[image: Andreana Weiner as Kestra]

Comment: Never forget Star Trek's motto: We hate continuity.

Comment: The answer is rather obvious - Kirsten is initially  the "placeholder" for Kestra in Lwaxana's mind, but only until she comes to grips with the suppressed memories. Afterwards, she remembers Kestra as she actually appeared.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because Lwaxana's memory sequence was triggered by Hedril's (played by Kirsten Dunst) resemblance to Kestra. So while Lwaxana was in her coma, her Metaconscious used Hedril to represent Kestra. The memory sequence of Kestra's death was stil within Lwaxana's head, and Deanna did not yet know about Kestra, so Hedril's image suddenly changing to a strange girl certainly would be confusing. Also, in-world, Lwaxana had not revealed the truth until then.

From the Wikipedia entry for the ["Dark Page" episode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dark_Page), pertinent parts bolded:

> Lwaxana Troi returns to the Enterprise, this time as the teacher of an
>   alien race learning to speak. Their native form of communication is
>   telepathy, but they want to learn spoken language in order to interact
>   with other races. **Lwaxana comes aboard with Maques and his young
>   daughter, Hedril, who is Lwaxana's star pupil**.
>
> Suspecting that Lwaxana is not her usual, flamboyant self, Deanna
>   tries to investigate. When Lwaxana starts showing signs of fatigue,
>   she is taken to Sick Bay to be examined. Beverly tells Lwaxana that
>   her interaction with the aliens is more taxing on her telepathic
>   glands than she is used to and is asked to refrain from telepathic
>   contact with them until she can recover. Deanna helps her mother by
>   verbally communicating with Maques and Hedril, but Lwaxana still uses
>   her telepathy when they don't grasp the verbal concepts. **After an
>   incident where Hedril falls into a pool of water in the arboretum,
>   Lwaxana falls into a coma.** With no signs of physical trauma, Crusher
>   deduces that her telepathic abilities have caused her mind to collapse
>   in on itself from the over use. Maques uses his ability to form a
>   bridge between Deanna and Lwaxana, and the former finds herself
>   walking through corridors like on the Enterprise. Lwaxana's mental
>   defenses pick up, first conjuring Deanna's father to distract her,
>   then an image of Picard himself ordering her to sever her connection.
>   **She sees past these ruses and encounters Hedril petting a wolf, but
>   the girl does not seem to know who "Hedril" is. Lwaxana then charges
>   in screaming for Deanna to get away from her, causing Deanna to break
>   her connection.**
>
> Deanna and Riker search through Lwaxana's things and find several
>   pieces of the puzzle missing; journal entries for a journal Lwaxana
>   kept since being married had blank pages from shortly after Deanna's
>   birth going on several years. **The image of Hedril in her mother's mind
>   does not add up.** She tries again to reach her mother, this time,
>   Deanna encounters the wolf by himself who chases after Deanna through
>   the deck until she encounters a Turbo Lift that opens into space.
>   Hearing her mother call for help, Deanna jumps in and lands in the
>   arboretum where Lwaxana had collapsed. Lwaxana is there, still begging
>   Deanna to leave, but Deanna refuses, stating that a repressed memory
>   is killing her and she must relive the memory in order to survive.
>   **Suddenly, an image of a human girl who looks like Hedril is playing by
>   the water with a puppy, and Lwaxana calls her Kestra. Deanna urges
>   Lwaxana to relive what happened, and she tearfully remembers a tragedy
>   when Kestra ran after the puppy when it got away, though it was
>   unclear what had caused her death. Lwaxana's repressed memory of
>   Kestra and her resemblance to Hedril led to her coma.** As Lwaxana
>   recalls happier memories of Kestra, Deanna tells her to share them so
>   she can learn about the sister she never knew. The women awaken in
>   Sick Bay holding hands.